# argc and argv in vstudio - to upper echo

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, printf, command-line-arguments, argv

i wrote a code that basically do the same thing of `echo` command in bash shell; but if read as argument `-c` uppercase all input argv. But, if i input `hello -c`, i've as only output `argc = 3`

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i,j;

    printf("argc = %d\n", argc);
    if (!strcmp(argv[argc-1], "-c"))
        for (i = 1; i < argc-1; ++i){
            for (j = 0; j != '\0'; ++j)
                putchar((char)toupper(argv[i][j]));
            putchar('\n');
        }
    else for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, in your code

```
  for (j = 0; j != '\0'; ++j)
```

is problematic. You should be checking the array element against null. It should rather read

```
for (j = 0; argv[i][j] != '\0'; ++j)
```

That said, [`putchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putchar) takes an `int` as argument, so you don't need to *cast* the return value of [`toupper()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/toupper).